# Convert Ruby Hash to ranks with no repeats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, sorting, hashmap

```
[{:listing_id=>1, :vote_size=>1, :created_at=>Wed, 13 Nov 2019 02:19:45 UTC +00:00},
 {:listing_id=>2, :vote_size=>0, :created_at=>Thu, 14 Nov 2019 02:19:45 UTC +00:00},
 {:listing_id=>3, :vote_size=>0, :created_at=>Fri, 15 Nov 2019 02:19:45 UTC +00:00}]
```

I have the following hash of listing IDs, the number of votes and the created_at date for said listing in Ruby (higher vote_size is better), and I'd like to rank them. In other words, I want to get the rank from some sort of function and then update the rank on the listing via listing.update_attribute(:rank, function-call) or something of that sort. Rank 1 is the best. If there are listings with the same amount of votes only one of them should get the rank and the other listing should get a rank below. (Let's say the tiebreaker is the listing created_at date, whoever created the listing first gets the higher rank.)

This is what I have so far and well I'm stuck lol and could really use some help.

```
namespace :server do
  desc "update the listings rank"
  task update_listing_rank: :environment do
      listings = Listing.all
      all_listings_with_votes = total_votes_for_listing listings


      all_listings_with_votes.map{ |e|
          puts all_listings_with_votes.index(e) + 1
        }

  end

  def total_votes_for_listing listings
    listings.map do |listing|
      {listing_id: listing.id, vote_size: listing.votes.size, created_at: listing.created_at}
    end
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a big hint... Take your array and

```
arr.sort{|x,y| x[:vote_size] <=> y[:vote_size]}
```

This will give you a sorted array of vote sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, that means we sort by combination vote_size and created_at, `vote_size` descending and `created_at` ascending in case there are two equal values for `vote_size`

```
an_array.sort_by {|a| [-a[:vote_size] , a[:created_at]] }
```

Comment: ...and then `arr[i]` has rank `i+1` if `arr` is the array returned by this expression.